# Multiple pdf files in one embed

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext, embed

I need your help over a problem I have. Actually, I have a page with a simple embed which displays a PDF file.
I got a request to add another PDF file to the same embed (or at least to do something which would look like it).

I searched some solutions and not finding a simple one, I'm thinking about using iTextSharp to merge both files (by getting their stream from their url), merging them into a new pdf file and display this resulting file into the embed.

But I'm just telling myself it's a bit too much for such a simple modification... And so I'm here asking you if someone would have a better idea ? From what I searched on stackoverflow and google it looks like I will have to take the merge solution but hey, we never know '^^

Answer (score 1):

A simpler option would be to merge the two PDF files using either a free online tool or Adobe Combine Files option and then adding that newly combined PDF to your site. Unless I am missing something, there is no real reason or benefit to do this using code.

Comment: The problem is that we're targetting files which are not in our servers (but still in the company) and we don't know whan they could change since they are legal documents :/

Comment: Hmmmm that does make it a bit tricky. I still think the best option is to do some research on how often you expect the documents to change. If it is very infrequently then I suggest loading them onto your server as a combined PDF. If they change very often then perhaps your other option may be better

Comment: I finally did a pdf which is manually merged. The documents aren't modified much (like once a year) so it was too much of a hassle only for this. Thank you anyway.